# Number from bind_result breaks the array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

this is my code to retreive information and send back to ajax:

```
else if(isset($_POST['act']) && $_POST['act']=='getbook'){
$book = normalize_str(htmlentities(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $_POST['book']), ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
$filecat = '../books/'.$book.'/'.$book.'.txt';
$catlist = file($filecat, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$mysqli = new mysqli($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName);
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

$query = "SELECT `id`,`title`,`price`,`image`,`description`,`category`,`enablerating`,`rating` FROM ".$PapierTableName." WHERE book = ? ORDER BY position ASC, title ASC;";
$prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);

if($prepared){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $book);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->bind_result($iden, $title, $price, $image, $description, $category, $enrat, $rating);
    if($result)
    {
        $rit = array();
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            $rit[] = array(

                invert_str(html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                $price,
                invert_str(html_entity_decode($image, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                invert_str(html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                invert_str(html_entity_decode($category, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                $enrat,
                $rating,
                $iden
            );
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $count = count($catlist);
        $ret = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < $count ; $i++)
            $ret= array_merge($ret, search($rit, 4, $catlist[$i]));
        file_put_contents('tre.txt',print_r($ret,true));
        echo json_encode($ret);
    }
    else
        file_put_contents('binderror.txt', $stmt->error);
}
else
    file_put_contents('connecterror.txt',$stmt->error);
}
```

My problem is that if I add `$iden` to the array it doens't work anymore, I mean that I have no array,if I print it with print_r I have no output.I have also tried to use `(string)$iden`

I can connect to the database and all the information are already checked(value and existence)
**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**
WITHOUT `$iden`.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => DB9
        [1] => 200031
        [2] => //localhost/css/images/objectimg/Aston Martin/db9.jpg
        [3] => some html
        [4] => DB9
        [5] => 1
        [6] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Rapid S
        [1] => 200000
        [2] => //localhost/css/images/objectimg/Aston Martin/vanq.jpg
        [3] => some html
        [4] => Rapid S
        [5] => 1
        [6] => 0
    )
```

)

WITH `$iden`

```
Array
(
)
```

WITH `$iden` AT THE END:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => DB9
        [1] => 200031
        [2] => //localhost/css/images/objectimg/Aston Martin/db9.jpg
        [3] => some html
        [4] => DB9
        [5] => 1
        [6] => 0
        [7] => 42
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Rapid S
        [1] => 200000
        [2] => //localhost/css/images/objectimg/Aston Martin/vanq.jpg
        [3] => some html
        [4] => Rapid S
        [5] => 1
        [6] => 0
        [7] => 45
    )
```

)

Comment: Do you have any output in `binderror.txt`?

Comment: No,I don't even see the file in the directory...

Comment: Are you displaying all errors? `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: I'm using xampp,but however this is my "header" ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '604800');
require_once ('../admin/dbi.php');
session_start();

Comment: Ok,the problem is that I can't anything at the beginning of the array, in others positions it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get something straight, you're not saving any time (or making the code prettier) by creating multiple variables in a single line, it's really time to hit the "enter" button once you throw out your semicolon.

The reason why no one has bothered to give you a proper answer is because, well, your code is really hard to read.

You should, to begin with, start by structuring your code way better, something like this should be considered aswell:

- Actually make sure that something is posted, don't assume that $_POST['book'] exists.
- Please show us all of the variables and functions you're using when you ask for help, showing us the values of $Hostname,$Username,$Password,$DatabaseName might actually help.
- $PapierTableName? Just define it in the query, or bind the name as-well into the query.
- Structure the query as a string, then prepare the string which holds the query.
- You're missing a semicolon in the query.
- Using $rit[$i] is pointless, using $rit[] = will works as good with appending data to the array.
- Take a look at utf8_encode, I think you're over-complexing your code.
- $ret = array_merge($ret, search($rit, 4, $catlist[$i]))  is overwriting everything you do, you have to do $ret[] = array_merge($ret, search($rit, 4, $catlist[$i]));

So combined, something like this will be much more structured:

```
<?php
$postedBook = isset($_POST['book']) ? $_POST['book'] : false;

if($postedBook != false)
{
    $Hostname = 'localhost';
    $Username = 'root';
    $Password = '';
    $DatabaseName = 'dbName';

    $book = normalize_str(htmlentities(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $postedBook), ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
    $filecat = '../books/'.$book.'/'.$book.'.txt';
    $catlist = file($filecat, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $mysqli = new mysqli($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName);
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM PapierTable WHERE book = ? ORDER BY position ASC, title ASC;";
    $prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);

    if($prepared)
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $book);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->bind_result($iden, $title, $price, $image, $description, $category, $enrat, $rating);
        if($result)
        {
            $rit = array();
            while($stmt->fetch())
            {
                $rit[] = array(
                    invert_str(html_entity_decode($title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                    $price,
                    invert_str(html_entity_decode($image, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                    invert_str(html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                    invert_str(html_entity_decode($category, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                    $enrat,
                    $rating
                );
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $count = count($catlist);
            $ret = array();
            for($i = 0; $i < $count ; $i++)
            {
                $ret[] = array_merge($ret, search($rit, 4, $catlist[$i]))
            }
            echo json_encode($ret);
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents('binderror.txt', $stmt->error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        file_put_contents('connecterror.txt',$stmt->error);
    }
}
?>
```

I'm not sure if that will fix your problem, but if it didn't then it should at least be way easier for your to find out what's wrong.

Most of errors that occur are very common and basic, but un-structured code makes them hell to find.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the help and the suggestions, but the problem still persists, I have added some array output example in the main post

Comment: Founded the error: I had to change also the index position inside the search function...search($rit, 5, $catlist[$i]));