# Change string in an array from file read and rewrite

Tags: php, arrays, file

basically what I want to do is to read a file and then change a string with another one,at this moment I have written this:

```
$pap=file('../papier.js');
    $count=count($pap);
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        if(strpos($pap[$i],"url: 'php/function.php'")){
            $url=dirname(dirname(curPageURL())).'/php/function.php';
            str_replace("url: 'php/function.php'",$url,$pap[$i]);
        }
    }

    $fs=fopen('../papier.js','w+');
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        fwrite($fs,$pap[$i]);
    fclose($fs);
```

it finds the right key,but I can't see any change in the file...
this is part of the file that should be changed:

```
(function($){
$.fn.papier = function (book, params) {var id=$(this);var request= $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/function.php',
        data: {act:'getOpt',book: book},
        dataType : 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
            id.append('<img id="papierloadinggifimage" src="css/images/loader.gif"/>');
        },
        success : function (opt) {
            if(opt[0]!=false){
                var request= $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php/function.php',
                data: {act:'getbook',book: book},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing "str_replace" but you're not using the result at all.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 Was hard to find

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you also solve this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623709/number-from-bind-result-breaks-the-array-php